# Clear cache of index page in drupal

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, drupal

I have tried the code below to clear the cache of the index page to show the latest content to the user.

```
<filesMatch "index.html">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

But when I try this code it gives forbidden error.

Comment: Run "apachectl -t" (or apache2ctl) , it will check the conf syntax

Comment: trying to remove cache when my site is up..

Comment: Why do you have to clear cache by apache conf ? You don't have varnish or memcache ?

Comment: look when there is a change I put a maintenance page then it will automatically maintain a cache for that page and once site is ready for end user then it will still show cache page i.e maintaince page to end user , I am trying to resolve this to write a code in such a way that it will not maintain any cache for maintenance page

Comment: try to check .htaccess file at root site directory , and remove "index.html" from line : 
# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm